# Update MongoDb data inside a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDb Database with a collection called `rooms`. In `rooms`, I want to search for a particular object by the `roomId` property. I want to update the array contents in the found object. For instance, initially, before making a request to that endpoint, the desired data looks like this:

```
{
    available: true,
    _id: 60817a403170bf49185c7db7,
    player1: "Jack",
    player2: "Adam",
    roomId: "ABCDE",
    pieces: [
        {
            point: [6, 0],
            player: "1",
            type: "P"
        },
        ...
    ],
    __v: 0
}
```

After making a request like `http://localhost:8000/room/ABCDE?x1=6&y1=0&x2=4&y2=0`, the data in mongodb should update to

```
{
    available: true,
    _id: 60817a403170bf49185c7db7,
    player1: "Jack",
    player2: "Adam",
    roomId: "ABCDE",
    pieces: [
        {
            point: [4, 0], /* DATA UPDATED */
            player: "1",
            type: "P"
        },
        ...
    ],
    __v: 0
}
```

This is my `api.js` file, what should the code be in the comments in order to execute this?

```
const express = require('express');
const GameRoom = require('../models/room');
const router = express.Router();

router.put('/room/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    GameRoom.findOne({roomId: req.params.id})
        .then(data => {
            const pieces = data.pieces;
            for (let i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
                if (pieces[i].point[0] === parseInt(req.query.x1) &&
                        pieces[i].point[1] === parseInt(req.query.y1)) {
                    pieces[i].point = [req.query.x2, req.query.y2];
                    break;
                }
            }         
            // Take the modified pieces array and update it
        }).catch(next);
});
```

Comment: what if there are multiple object in `pieces` array? you mean to update it everywhere in `pieces` array when matching number found right ?

Comment: No, the PUT method is actually a method for playing a piece on a chess board. The initial and final point is passed as query parameters. I first located the entire game data stored in `data`. I extracted the list of pieces `data.pieces` and then found the piece and changed it. Now I have to update this modified pieces to mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$[<identifier>]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to find and update the points:

```
GameRoom.updateOne(
  { roomId: req.params.id },
  { $set: { "pieces.$[el].point.0": req.query.x2, "pieces.$[el].point.1": req.query.y2 }}, 
  { arrayFilters: [ { "el.point.0": req.query.x1, "el.point.1": req.query.y1 } ]}
);
```

Or if you just want to update the first pieces that match the condition then you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) with [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator:

```
GameRoom.updateOne(
  { 
    roomId: req.params.id, 
    pieces: {$elemMatch: {"point.0": req.query.x1, "point.1": req.query.y1}}} 
  },
  { $set: {"pieces.$.point.0": req.query.x2, "pieces.$.point.1": req.query.y2} }
);
```

Comment: How do I return the updated data to the client after this operation?

Comment: if so you can use `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `updateOne`